# Addresses of Delphi and C++ WinAPI functions differ when they shouldn't

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010, getprocaddress

In C++, if you try to get a function pointer of a Windows API function, that pointer points to the same address you would get if you used `GetProcAddress` on the name of that function and it's respective module. For example:

```
&MessageBoxA == GetProcAddress("User32.dll", "MessageBoxA");
```

would be `true`. However, in Delphi, that is not the case. This code:

```
@MessageBoxA = GetProcAddress('User32.dll', 'MessageBoxA');
```

Would *not* be `true`, and in my test, `@MessageBoxA` was `0x0040bd18` while the equivalent `GetProcAdress` returned what the test's C++ counterpart did, `0x7550fd1e`.

So now for my question: why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address with the 0x004.. is the address of the declaration of the imported api function (in `windows.pas` for `MessageBoxA`) to have it [statically loaded](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/librariesandpackagesov_xml.html#537461746963204C6F6164696E67), hence it will of course reside in the executable image (which have a base address of 0x00400000 by default). The actual function called is in the image of the library loaded to the memory of that function resides in. You can get the image base of the library with `GetModuleHandle`. In your case it will probably be something with 0x75... With the C++ test, you're probably linking with the runtime library, so the function is dynamically loaded anyway.

Comment: I don't think this answer fully covers why Delphi programs have stubs for imported DLL functions and C programs don't.

Comment: @Rob - Isn't that why Delphi does not require .lib files? C programs have the definitions in header files and addresses of the imported functions in the .lib file which is linked to the idata section to get resolved by the Win32 loader?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No it is not. Linkage is different for most C++ compilers. They don't use thunks and the addresses are fixed up by the loaded.

Comment: @David - I'm not sure what you say contradicts what I said.

Comment: @Sertac OK, but it's not really about .lib files. It's perfectly possible to link without .lib files, and without thunks. It's compiler choice. C++ linkers could go either way. All an import .lib file provides is a function name (in case exported name differs from import name) and a dll name. So too could Delphi. Delphi could avoid thunks if the devs had made that choice. Thunks reduce exe size at the cost of an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: @David - Thanks, I was under the impression that they require linking to import libs for static loading.

Comment: @Sertac No. It's not required. It's how it tends to be done. Much of that is historical. GCC can link statically to a dll with no lib file. You supply the dll itself and the linker works it out. Remember also that C++ lang has no equivalent to Delphi's external. So that info comes from outside the source.